# How to change the name of the apk file?

Tags: android, cordova, phonegap-build, phonegap

I build apk file with help of **https://build.phonegap.com/apps/** portal evrey time I build debug or release apk file  the names are:

`______debug.apk` or `______release.apk`

I want to change the name of the release apk to something more significant, for example `MyProject-v2.apk`.

Any idea how can I change the name of the the apk file when it build?

Comment: Why not just rename the apk after it is created?

Comment: @NongthonbamTonthoi, is it possible to set the name in config.xml file and to get apk file with significant name on build?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, sadly you cannot control the file name in the config.xml, but the file name doesn't matter. In the config.xml, you specify the name of your app as it will appear to the users on their mobiles, and that's what matters.

If you like to give the file a specific name for your own file management (which is what I do too), you'll have to manually rename the file every time you create a new build.

Answer (score 2):

The thing you should know is that  APK names does not matter in its file name, What matters is what you said in the `AndroidManifest.xml` in the `Application` label:

```
 android:label="@string/app_name"
```

This is the only app name and it can even be different from `package name` so the apk being called `______debug.apk` or `______release.apk` doesnt matter it is just to differenciate if it is debug or release. You can just rename it just like any file in your computer even `Michael.apk`. And still all android phones will ignore the file names and go get the label at `android:label="@string/app_name"` so just copy the file and change it to anything you want and it works.

Answer (score 1):

You can rename it as a file.

The installed apk name is same as what you defined in manifest.

Answer (score 1):

You can configure naming of you builds in gradle configuration

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Add this to your android{} close in your module's build.gradle:

```
 // determine the apk file name when produced
applicationVariants.all { variant ->
    variant.outputs.each { output ->
        output.outputFile = new File(
                output.outputFile.parent,
                output.outputFile.name.replace("app", "YourAppNameHere-V${variant.versionName}"))
    }
}
```

the V is for the version number.

Comment: Your answer is outdated.
* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
> groovy.lang.GroovyRuntimeException: Cannot set the value of read-only property 'outputFile' for ApkVariantOutputImpl_Decorated{apkData=Main{type=MAIN, fullName=debug, filters=[], versionCode=20102,.

Answer (score 1):

Inside modules `build.gradle` file, add following line to `android { defaultConfig { X } }`

```
setProperty('archivesBaseName', "YourAppName-$versionCode")
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case I just renamed the file app_release.apk to appname.apk
and it works for me.

Same for app_debug.apk to appname_debug.apk

In project directory:

[image: Example]

While Installing

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You cannot control the file name in the config.xml. But if you have a self signed certificate and want to rename the apk, you can do it with zipalign:

```
zipalign.exe -v 4 platforms\android\app\build\outputs\apk\release\app-release-unsigned.apk platforms\android\app\build\outputs\apk\release\YouyAppName-v2.apk
```